# C++ - Calculate execution time of a function always = 0?

Tags: c++, clock, execution-time

I use clock() in  library to calculate excution time of a function, which is BubbleSort(..) function in my code below. But probleam is that the return execution time always = 0 (and it shows no unit, too).
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>
    using namespace std;

    void BubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i<n; i++)
            for (int j = n-1; j >=i; j-- )
                if (arr[j] < arr[j-1])
                {
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j-1];
                    arr[j-1] = temp;
                }
        return;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int arr[] = {4,1,7,2,6, 17, 3, 2, 8,1};
        int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
        cout << "Before Bubble Sort: \n";
        for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
        }
        clock_t start_s=clock(); // begin
        BubbleSort(arr,len);
        clock_t stop_s=clock();  // end
        cout << "\nAfter Bubble Sort: \n";
        for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
        }
        // calculate then print out execution time - currently always returns 0 and I don't know why
        cout << "\nExecution time: "<< (double)(stop_s - start_s)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
        //system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

I haven't known how to fix this problem yet .. So hope you guys can help me with this. Any comments would be very appreciated. Thanks so much in advanced !

Comment: What's the value of `stop_s` and `start_s`? Try printing those out, to try to narrow down where the issue might exist.

Comment: what do you expect? How does your computer decode video in realtime? Imagine, sorting one line of pixels would take around one second... You're expecting 1 second resolution anyway, and clock() isn't more precise either

Comment: Start by tossing the per-sec division. Narrow that down first. And btw, this prints `3e-06` on my rig. Also, your bubble sort isn't correct. A bubble sort should have an escape if if *any* single j-level pass makes no swaps.

Comment: http://www.righto.com/2012/11/obama-on-sorting-1m-integers-bubble.html

Comment: I added this line and it comes out as 0.
std::cout<<"start: "<<start_s<<std::endl;

Comment: @WhozCraig That is an optimization to bubble sort not a requirement of it (at least thats what i remember being taught.

Comment: @thermite it isn't required to sort, but it is required to *be a bubblesort*. It is not an optimization. Even the *base* algorithm (at least in my copy of Knuth), has this construct, and I've never seen a *real* bubblesort without it (though I have seen plenty of algorithms people *call* bubblesort where it is absent). Complexity of bubble sort by-defintion must be `O(n)` if the input is already sorted, and that is not possible without that escape clause.

Comment: @WhozCraig I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 2):

As you have only a very small array, the execution time is probably much shorter than the resolution of clock(), so you either have to call the sort algorithm repeatedly or use another time source.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code as such and both start end stop have the value of 0. (ubuntu 13.10)

```
    std::cout<<"start: "<<start_s<<std::endl;
    BubbleSort(arr,len);
    clock_t stop_s=clock();  // end
    std::cout<<"stop: "<<stop_s<<std::endl;
```

you probably want something more like gettimeofday()

this http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/120862/clock-always-returns-0 is an interesting discussion of the same thing. the poster concluded that clock()(on his machine) had a resolution of about 1/100 of a sec. and your code is probably ( almost certainly) running faster than that